# after changing with javascript, new Form Field Value will not be sent with submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea, submit

I have a problem changing field value of a form by javascript.
first, I have put a button in my form for user to change the contents of the field with javascript. in this function, the textarea value will be replaced with an ordered list. the function is:

```
function makelist(sender)
{
    var inputname="mytextarea";
    var newvalue = sender.form.elements[inputname].value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '</li><li>');
    newvalue='<ol><li>'+newvalue+'</li></ol>';
    sender.form.elements[inputname].value=newvalue;
    sender.form.elements[inputname].innerHTML=newvalue; 
}
```

the code works well and the textarea value changes as I expect. but the problem is that when I submit the form, still the old value of the textarea will be sent with the form.

I could not figure out what is wrong with the approach. I would be very grateful receiving any hint or idea.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you changing the `innerHTML` of `<textarea>`..? 0__0

Comment: Tilwin Joy, not any reason, I think I should delete that line.

Comment: That might actually help you. Until you explain how you're calling this function and share the corresponding `html`, it's unclear what's `sender`, is your selectors right etc..